# Update field value but also apply cap?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to update the value of a field but cap it at the same time?:

```
UPDATE users SET num_apples=num_apples-1 WHERE xxx = ?
```

I don't want to the field "num_apples" to fall below zero. Can I do that in one operation?

Thanks

-----  Update  ------------------

```
UPDATE users SET num_apples=num_apples-1 WHERE user_id = 123 AND num_apples > 0;
```

If I only have an index on "user_id", and not "num_apples", is that going to be bad for performance? I'm not sure how mysql implements this operation. I'm hoping that the WHERE on the user_id part makes it fast. I have to perform this operation somewhat frequently.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `WHERE` condition specifying only rows > 0, so it won't update any rows into the negative.

```
UPDATE users SET num_apples=num_apples-1 WHERE num_apples > 0;
```

#### Update

Following your subquestion on indexing, as always, the way to test performance is to benchmark it for yourself.  Examine the `EXPLAIN` for the query and make sure it is using the index on `user_id` (it should be).  And finally, don't worry too much about performance of this simple operation until it becomes a problem. You don't have an index on `num_apples` now, but could you not add one if performance wasn't scaling to your needs?

Comment: Ah ok good idea - I updated the question above - is doing the WHERE on "num_apples > 0" going to be bad for performance if I don't have an index on "num_apples"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create 2 indexes as only one will be used. You should index both fields into one index. The index should be the pair user_id and num_apples:

```
alter table t add index(user_id, num_apples) yourNewIndex;
```

You can actually remove the previous index as this will also include it:

```
alter table t drop index yourOldIndex;
```

Before dropping it you can get information on what index is being used by running:

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE users SET num_apples=num_apples-1
WHERE user_id = 123 AND num_apples > 0;
```

If the index used is the yourNewIndex, then MySQL realized that it is faster to use that than the previous one.

**Edit:**

> do I even need any checks? Will mysql prevent the value from going < 0 by default in that case?

Yes you will. You'll get a data truncation error when running the update if you do not control that:

```
Data truncation: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range
```

Comment: Interesting, what if the column is of type unsigned int - do I even need any checks? Will mysql prevent the value from going < 0 by default in that case?

Comment: Anwswered in the answer itself.